# need Scroll Table with Fixed Header

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Please I need a help:
My problem that: I need to display a table and when I scrolling it the header was fixed.
That’s my code :
VF :

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="inputParameters" style="height:200px;overflow:auto;" >                             
                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="hic" align="left" value="{!getusedVoucher_List}" style="" var="f" columnswidth="100px,100px" cellpadding="4" border="1" rowClasses="odd,even" >
                        <apex:column headervalue="Name"  >
                            {!f.Name} 
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headervalue="Voucher Number" >
                            {!f.Voucher_Number__c}  
                        </apex:column >
                        <apex:column headervalue="Type">
                            {!f.Type__c}                                
                        </apex:column>                        
                        <apex:column headervalue="Description" >
                            {!f.Description__c}
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>                                 
                </apex:outputPanel>
```

Controller

```
public   List<Olympus_Voucher__c> getusedVoucher_List{get;set;} 
 getusedVoucher_List = Database.query('SELECT Name, Olympus_Server__c,Type__c,Voucher_Number__c,Description__c  FROM Olympus_Voucher__c ');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not an option for this using a PageblockTable.  You will either need to use a `<apex:repeat>`method and build the table yourself, or use a javascript library like jqGrid to render the data.